# lightgbm.sklearn.LGBMRegressor failed to fit simple line

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, regression, lightgbm

I'm pretty new with LightGBM and I'm trying to fit simple line via LGBMRegressor.

```
import numpy as np
import lightgbm as lgbm
xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 30).reshape((-1, 1)) 
ys = np.linspace(0, 10, 30)    
reg = lgbm.sklearn.LGBMRegressor()
reg.fit(xs, ys) 
print reg.predict(xs)
>>> array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

What i'm doing wrong? Maybe i need more features?

My LightGBM version is 2.0.7 (from github source), python version is 2.7.12

PS Sorry for my poor English

Comment: I have not reproduced your setup, but i checked it on my own setup using python3.6 and lightgbm 2.0.3. (installed with pip). As a result got a different output (which looked correct). Is your python a 64-bit version? Otherwise your code seems fine.

Comment: @ChristopherSchröder thank you for comment! Yes, my python2.7.12 is 64-bit. Probably i should try my code with lgbm 2.0.3

Comment: I also tried it using the 2.0.7 version later on. Still produced reasonable output. Maybe you can try using the pip installer? Which operating system do you use?

Comment: @ChristopherSchröder Sorry for late response, i just checked version 2.0.10. Predict  method returns quite reasonable values. With combination Viktoria Malyasova's answer and n_estimators=<some big number> option it's possible to achieve pretty  nice results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set parameters min_data_in_leaf = 1, min_data_in_bin = 1.